# Trying to echo buttons for HTML table

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to understand when I run the btn_actions function I have nothing returned to me. I'm attempting to get two buttons to be echoed out in my table.

```
echo $this->functions_model->btn_actions(1);
die();

public function btn_actions($item_id)
{
    $content = '<div class="controls center">';
    $content = $this->btn_edit($item_id);
    $content = $this->btn_delete($item_id);
    $content = '</div>';

    return $content;
}

public function btn_edit($item_id)
{
    $button = '<a class="tip" href="'. current_url() . '/edit/' .  $item_id  .'" oldtitle="Edit Task" aria-describeby="ui-tooltip-8"><span class="icon12 icomoon-icon-pencil"></span></a>';
    return $button;
}

public function btn_delete($item_id)
{
    $button = '<a class="tip" href="'. current_url() . '/soft-delete/' . $item_id .'" oldtitle="Delete Task"><span class="icon12 icomoon-icon-remove"></span></a>';
    return $button;
}
```

Comment: Just add . i.e  $content .= ; u missed the concatenation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate using `.`

```
$content = '<div class="controls center">';
$content .= $this->btn_edit($item_id);
$content .= $this->btn_delete($item_id);
$content .= '</div>';

return $content;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I forgot to do that. Simple mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
echo $this->functions_model->btn_actions(1);
die();

public function btn_actions($item_id)
{
   $content = '<div class="controls center">';
   $content = $content . $this->btn_edit($item_id);
   $content = $content . $this->btn_delete($item_id);
   $content = $content . '</div>';
   return $content;
 }

public function btn_edit($item_id)
{
   $button = '<a class="tip" href="'. current_url() . '/edit/' .  $item_id  .'" oldtitle="Edit Task" aria-describeby="ui-tooltip-8"><span class="icon12 icomoon-icon-pencil"></span></a>';
   return $button;
}

public function btn_delete($item_id)
{
    $button = '<a class="tip" href="'. current_url() . '/soft-delete/' . $item_id .'" oldtitle="Delete Task"><span class="icon12 icomoon-icon-remove"></span></a>';
   return $button;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I forgot to do that. Simple mistakes.